# Is the usage of special attributes discouraged?

Tags: python

The Python docs state at https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy :

> Some of the type descriptions below contain a paragraph listing ‘special attributes.’ These are attributes that provide access to the implementation and are not intended for general use. Their definition may change in the future.

So, for me it sounds like the usage of special attributes is discouraged.

Is that really the case?

And if so: is there a ‘non-special‘ way to access each special attribute (like the built-in function `len` for `__len__`)?

---

Just to make clear, what I am talking about:

In case of user-defined functions, the special attributes are:

- __doc__
- __name__
- __qualname__
- __module__
- __defaults__
- __code__
- __globals__
- __dict__
- __closure__
- __annotations__
- __kwdefaults__

Answer (score 0):

Usually this special attribute are used when working with class objects(magic functions/dunder functions and such) but yes, those attributes have a way to be accessed in a 'non-special' way as you put it, and should not be used just anywhere. Here are a few examples of alternatives for some of them. For the **global** you have the global key word(you avoid this practice as much as possible)

```
x = 'hello'

def egs():
   global x
   print(x)   #prints out hello
```

`__dict__` is just a way to make an object into a dictionary, the keyword for this is for non class object and instances would be `dict`, `__str__` works exactly like `str` with the exact same principle as i highlighted earlier and the list goes on. Like i said in the beginning these special method are usually only used when dealing with classes and class instances. there are alternatives for the **majority** **(not all to the best of my knowledge)** of them for non class objects